# Unable to install Microsoft sharepoint generator in MacBook pro

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, modern-experience, spfx-tooling

I am getting below error and messages while trying to install Microsoft SharePoint generator in MacBook pro:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.13.0 <13.0.0 || >=14.15.0 <15.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for yeoman-generator@5.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=12.10.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: yeoman-generator@5.4.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.13.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.13.0 <13.0.0 || >=14.15.0 <15.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.13.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @azure/core-paging@1.2.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @azure/core-paging@1.2.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @azure/logger@1.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @azure/logger@1.0.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @azure/core-auth@1.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.0","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @azure/core-auth@1.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Framework v1.13.0 is supported on the following Node.js versions:

- Node.js v12.13.0+ (Erbium)
- Node.js v14.15.0+ (Fermium)

Try using either of above Node.js version to install `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0`

**Source**: [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

---

Also, I will recommend you to look at the SPFx compatibility matrix for compatible versions of common tools and libraries: [SPFx development environment compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)

Comment: These are the below versions of different components I was using in the windows system, the same setting I did in Macbook.
── gulp@3.9.1
├── npm@6.14.11
└── yo@3.1.1
------ node -v10.24.0
and If I check version of microsoft sharepoint generator .
I get below detail as empty.
npm ls -g --depth=0 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

Comment: and now I am getting the below error:This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0, current version is 2.10.3, try reinstalling latest version of 'yo' or use '--ignore-version-check' option

Answer (score 0):

Finally the configuration I am using is working fine with the node -v -12.13.0
├── @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-cli@2.3.0
├── npm@6.12.0
├── typescript@3.3.4000
└── yo@4.3.0